# pymongo : to check if we have connected to MongoDB database

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

```
client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db = client[DB_NAME]

def db_connect():
    #connecting to a DB in mongoDB
    try:
        if client.get_database(DB_NAME):
            print("Connection Successful!")
            return True
    except:
        print("Please check your connection")
        return False

def db_close():
    print ("Connection Getting Closed")
    client.close()
```

I am trying to achieve a task, only if the connection exists by pymongo, then return True so that the functions can proceed, else it should return False and a message to check connection. So that we don't proceed further.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT 1 : Accepted Solution

```
Successfully added user: {
"user" : "ash",
"roles" : [
    {
        "role" : "readWrite",
        "db" : "myDB"
    },
    "clusterAdmin"
]
```

}

I added a user using the above code snippet and then used the following script.

```
DB_NAME = "myDB"
client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db = client[DB_NAME]
def db_connect():
    #connecting to a DB in mongoDB
    try:
        if db.authenticate("ash","password"):
            print("Connection Successful!")
            return True
    except:
        print("Please check your connection")
        return False

def db_close():
    print ("Connection Getting Closed")
    client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db_connect()
    db_close()
```

I have used this code snippet to connect to my DB
Now getting connected to the DB
I have the database in my PC and I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to use the `authenticate` method anyway inside connection function, so you could do it as following:

```
In [12]: client = MongoClient(DB_MACHINE, DB_PORT)
In [13]: db = client.db_name
In [16]: if db.authenticate(DB_USER, DB_PASS, source=DB_SOURCE):
             # authenticated, do ...
         else:
             # not authenticated, not connected, do something else
```

Comment: `Successfully added user: {
 "user" : "ash",
 "roles" : [
  {
   "role" : "readWrite",
   "db" : "myDB"
  },
  "clusterAdmin"
 ]
` 

I used this to create my user

and I am using this way to connect to my database I am  not able to figure out what mistake I am making.

Comment: Well what mistake are you getting when authenticating?

Comment: I couldn't figure out the error.
As you can see from my code above, I have made some changes.
Its just not authenticating. Is there any way to figure it out?

Comment: So it's not authenticating? What does `db.authenticate(DB_USER, DB_PASS, source=DB_SOURCE)` return to you?

Comment: I removed the source=DB_SOURCE part from the authenticate function. Now it is working properly after making user in the MondoDB and using the right credentials. I am a new programmer and I dont have enough credits to upvote your answer. I wish to do that whenever I would get them in the near future.